# Various questions from a discrete mathematics course

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

1. Proof that $$ \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\p\end{bmatrix} = \begin{cases} 1 & p \equiv1,11\mod 12 \\ -1 & p \equiv5,7\mod 12\end{cases}$$
2. Consider the group $G$. An involution in $G$ is an element $a \in G$ of order two, i.e. $a^2 = e$, with $e$ the identity in $G$. Suppose that all elements ($e$ excluded of course) of $G$ are involutions. Proof that $G$ is abelian. Can you say something more about $G$ with the assumption that $G$ is finite?
3. A palindromic number is a number that remains the same when its digits are reversed. Proof that all palindromic numbers with an even number of digits are always divisible by 11. Is the converse also true (proof/counterexample).
4. Suppose that $X$ is a set with cardinality $n$ and that $U$ is a set of subsets of $X$ with cardinality $d$ $(d\le n)$. The elements of $U$ are chosen in a special way so that all subsets with cardinality $t$ ($t$ is a fixed number, $d \le t \le n$) contain exactly $1$ element of $U$. Suppose that $S$ is a subset of $X$ with $|S| = i, t\le i \le n$. Find the number of elements of $U$ that are contained in $S$.

I'm struggling with answering these questions. Any hints? It doesn't matter if you don't know all of the answers to each question. All help is welcome!

An enormous 'thank you'!

**EDIT (here are my attempts, by *popular* demand):**

1) We want to prove that $x^2 \equiv 3$ has a solution $\operatorname{mod} p$ if $p \equiv 1, 11, \mod 12$. Is this proof similar to proving -1 is a square modulo $p$? But where do the specific numbers 1, 11, 5 and 7 come from? Why modulo 12?

2) Take $g,h \in G$ randomly. We want to prove that $gh=hg$. Since $g$ and $h$ are elements of $G$, these elements have an inverse $g^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}$ resp. These inverses are also involutions. $G$ is a group, so the product of elements in $G$ is also an element in $G$. We get: $(gh)(gh)=e = (gh)(h^{-1} g^{-1})$ and $(hg)(hg)=e=(hg)(g^{-1} h^{-1}) $. This means that $(gh)^2 = (hg)^2$. Is this enough to conclude that $gh=hg$? Do I actually need the inverses, because I haven't really used them?

3) I have no clue here. Maybe something like this: suppose we have a palindromic number $n$ with $2k$ digits. When $k=1$, $n/11$ will give as a quotient consisting of one number from 1 to 9. For $k=2$, we'll have a quotient of 2 digits etc. I guess it's also useful to consider the set of residue classes modulo 11.

4) Honestly, I don't even understand the question.

Comment: An enormous "What have you done so far to tackle these questions"? At least show some effort, and better: don't ask so many questions at once.

Comment: I have an exam in 2 days and I find the exercises very hard. Of course I've already tried something myself before posting these questions, but the fact that I went to this site, means that my attempts weren't successful. I put multiple questions in one post, because the maximum amount of questions per day is six... Then I should've waited another day and I can't really do that right now because of my upcoming exam... So, an enormous 'you didn't have to attack me for asking help to people who have most likely more experience in maths and who actually want to help an undergrad student, like me'.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question to include context, that sort of thing is highly appreciated on this site. However we would really appreciate it if you could limit things to one question per post, as it would increase the number of answers you would receive and decrease the number of close votes (and nasty comments) you would receive. Help us help you.

Comment: Here is a hint for Question 3. $10^2 = 100 \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ and hence $10^{2n+1} + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod 11$ for all $n$.

Comment: Also Question 2 has been asked zillions of times before, so if you search this site you should be able to find a solution.